# Flask Form-Submit only returns GET method instead of POST method

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

So I'm trying to build some kind of mini-social media platform called FoodStock (for learning purposes). I made a page where you can create a new post and it uses the  `new_post.html` file as a render template. On the `new_post.html` file there's a `form` that only returns the `GET` method no matter what I try. Although it's clearly stated that I want the form to return a `POST` method when submitting the form, it always returns `GET`. I'm a newbie to Flask and webdev in general so I don't really know much about it. Hopefully someone can help.

Here's what it says when I click on the submit form button.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jul/2021 14:45:07] "POST /home/2/helloworld HTTP/1.1" 302 -
GET
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jul/2021 14:45:07] "GET /create_post/2/helloworld HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jul/2021 14:45:08] "GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

main code shown below. The home route works fine, just the create_post route that always receives a GET method.

```
@app.route('/home/<int:id>/<string:password>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home(id, password):
    if request.method == "POST":
        return redirect(f"/create_post/{id}/{password}")
    else:
        return render_template("home_page.html", posts=FoodPost.query.all(), id=id, password=password)

@app.route('/create_post/<int:id>/<string:password>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def create_post(id, password):
    if request.method == "POST":
        response = request.form
        new_post = FoodPost(title=response['title'], content=response['content'])

        try:
            db.session.add(new_post)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect(f"/home/{id}/{password}")
        except:
            return "There was an issue processing your post, please try again later :("
    else:
        print(str(request.method))
        return render_template("new_post.html", id=id, password=password)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

new_post.html file below

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head %}
<title>Food Stock: New Post</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block body%}
<div>
        <h1>New Post<h1>
</div>

<div class="form">
        <form action='/home/{{id}}/{{password}}' method='POST'>
                <label>Title</label>
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="title", id="title">

                <br>
                <br>

                <label>Content</label>
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="content", id="content">
                <input type="submit" value='Create Post' id="createpost">
        </form>
        
        <br>

        <form action='/home/{{id}}/{{password}}'>
                <input type="submit" value="Cancel" id="cancel">
        </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem this the action url.I give you a work flow when you click submit

when you click submit button in `new_post.html`,the page request to `home` route with `POST` method,the `home` route function do redirect as `redirect(f"/create_post/{id}/{password}")` with `GET` method
you should know all `redirect` in HTTP is `GET` method no matter the previous method is.
the `redirect(f"/create_post/{id}/{password}")` is tell browser to request another given url,so browser request `/create_post/{id}/{password}` with `GET` method.

so all your log history make sense.

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head %}
<title>Food Stock: New Post</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block body%}
<div>
        <h1>New Post<h1>
</div>

<div class="form">
        <!-- The problem is here,the action url -->
        <form action='/home/{{id}}/{{password}}' method='POST'>
        <!-- Replace it with this url will be fine-->
        <form action='/create_post/{{id}}/{{password}}' method='POST'>
                <label>Title</label>
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="title", id="title">

                <br>
                <br>

                <label>Content</label>
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="content", id="content">
                <input type="submit" value='Create Post' id="createpost">
        </form>
        
        <br>

        <form action='/home/{{id}}/{{password}}'>
                <input type="submit" value="Cancel" id="cancel">
        </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```